# %( convert negative number to positive in System.out.printf

Tags: java

The output of this code

```
System.out.printf("%d %(d %+d %05d\n", 3, -3, 3, 3);
```

is

```
3 (3) +3 00003
```

can somebody please explain why the -3 is printed as 3 in this statement?

Comment: Or just `System.out.printf("%(d", -3);` which prints `(3)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> can somebody please explain why the -3 is printed as 3 in this statement?

Its isn't, it is being printed as `(3)`

From the Javadoc for [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) say flag `(`

> The result will enclose negative numbers in parentheses

Comment: +1 for the link saying : The '(' numeric flag may be used to format negative numbers with parentheses rather than a minus sign.

Comment: It doesn't skip the negative sign, it uses `(n)` to show negative instead of `-` If you use a positive number there is no `()`

Comment: As I know, in Accounting the negative number is placed in between two brackets.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Banks are conservative and used Roman numerals for centuries longer than other mathematicians. Negative numbers were also controversial for centuries and banks preferred to say you where X in credit or X in debit and not use negative numbers sometimes using `(nnnn)`  I remember bank statements using negative numbers only relatively recently possibly due to the wide use of computers.

Answer (score 9):

The [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) help says that the format "(" means it will enclose negative numbers in parentheses.

> In bookkeeping, amounts owed are often represented by red numbers, or
>   a number in parentheses, as an alternative notation to represent
>   negative numbers.

From [Wikipedia: Negative Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number)